# Flutter - how to create column of buttons

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to create container with 3 buttons within.I have basic idea how to do this, like creating 3 containers with gesture detector and then separate them with divider, but i want to know if there is more clean way to do this.
[image]

Comment: `ListView.separated`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you've been looking for in the minimum viable way.

Source code:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: NewHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class NewHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<NewHomePage> createState() => _NewHomePageState();
}

class _NewHomePageState extends State<NewHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.separated(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
              dense: true,
              leading: const Icon(Icons.star),
              title: Text("Title: $index"),
              subtitle: Text("Subtitle: $index"),
              trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
              onTap: () {},
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return const Divider(height: 1, thickness: 1);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The above source code has static data / I can say it's without a custom model. If you want non-static data / created using a custom model, I can help you with that.